# skia failed to follow build instructions

Tags: c++, build, ninja, skia, gn

I am trying to build skia on windows platform and I am following official skia buid guide.
So what I have done till now:

- I downloaded visual studio 2019 with microsoft clang compiler via vs installer
- then I obtained *depot_tools* unzipped them and add to system PATH via control panel
  and using gclient command I confirmed that path was ok.
- then using `git clone https://skia.googlesource.com/skia.git` I got skia on my pc.

Having that done in skia dir I typed :

- python3 tools/git-sync-deps
- python3 bin/fetch-ninja

Ok now my questions. This command `python3 tools/git-sync-deps` has load a lot of things like like libpng, libwebp, or libjpeg-turbo. So what flags should I pass to GN to build skia? Where should I find these flags? Does microsoft clang compiler is the one that should I use to build skia.

Comment: My advice is to save yourself a few days of headaches and just pull skia via vcpkg. Google's libraries are always pains in the ass to build on Windows.

Comment: Why it's so hard to build such good 2d library. Is it google strategy for " open " source projects

Comment: Because windows is a second class citizen to Google. Linux is primary. Their tools are easier to work with on Linux.

Comment: Ok I have compiled without any flags. I get shit tons of .lib files. How to do add it to existing vs project without hassle

Comment: I event don't know what compiler was used

Comment: google tools probably are not building with Visual Studio, but i could be wrong